Managing PowerShell Session Closure and Client Connections on Windows 10
I am running a Vite application on a Windows machine. However, when I try to close the PowerShell window, it doesn't release the port used by the application. Is there a way to send a Ctrl + C command or force the closure of client connections when closing the PowerShell window?

